# Does FreeBSD 8.3 works similar with php 5.6 as FreebSD 10.3? Or how to make right dev environment

Tags: php, web-deployment, freebsd, system-administration, web-development-server

I've an interesting question about FreeBSD 8.3 and php 5.6.

Does php 5.6 works similar on FreeBSD 8.3 and FreeBSD 10.3?

I'm trying to make right development environment. Is it good to develop under FreeBSD 10.3 and deploy it to FreeBSD 8.3? Or it'd better use production and development server with similar OS version?

Sorry if it's newbie question:) If so please give a link to manual))

Thank you in advance!

Sincerely yours,

alwesu

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD 8.3 is end-of-life and not supported anymore. That means that PHP 5.6 may not work there, or contain bugs.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD 8.3 is not [currently supported](https://www.freebsd.org/security/security.html#sup). That said, it *should* work but I would be more concerned about your system than which version of PHP you can run.

I would encourage you to [upgrade](https://www.freebsd.org/security/security.html#how) your FreeBSD 8.3 system to 9.x then again to 10.x as soon as possible. If you have a generic kernel it is pretty simple task - just back up first :]

One of my servers started on FreeBSD 4.8 and is currently running 10.3. Hardware age should not be a problem so there is no excuse.

Just do not skip a major version during the upgrade.

If concerned, build a FreeBSD 8.3 test box and step over the process on that box first as a test. The [manual](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-upgrading.html) has a lot of info if you can not run `freebsd-update`.